# Get encrypted string when FETCH mail from IMAP

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, imap, tcpclient

I'm trying to write a IMAP mail client on C#.net with TCPClient and SSL. I can get past the connection and authentication just fine but when I fetch mail from imap.google.com, it return a encrypted string that I can't read at all. Something like:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UmU6IDMw5pyf5a6f57+S55Sf44Gu5oOF5aCx44Gr6Zai44GX44Gm?=
```

My FETCH commands are as below

```
"$ FETCH " + number + " body[header]\r\n"
"$ FETCH " + number + " body[text]\r\n"
```

What do I have to do to get the header and body of the mail to display correctly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This may be a language issue, but this is `encoded`, not `encrypted`.  Encoding means it has been changed for transmission, but can be easily reversed by anyone; Encrypted means it has been changed, and can only be reversed by someone with a secret key.

Answer (score 1):

> Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UmU6IDMw5pyf5a6f57+S55Sf44Gu5oOF5aCx44Gr6Zai44GX44Gm?=

This is not encrypted at all. This is simply the subject encoded using base64 according to the MIME standard, see [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt). Decoding it results in `Re: 30期実習生の情報に関して`.

In order to deal with such encodings you need to decode it according to the MIME standard, i.e. either read the standard and implement everything yourself or search for some existing library which implements RFC 2047.

Comment: To add, MIME is a surprisingly complicated topic.  There are these (encoded words) in RFC 2047; There is Parameter Value encoding (RFC 2231), Content-Transfer-Encoding (Quoted Printable and Base64: RFC 2045), character set encoding (RFC 2045, plus whatever specifies the encoding of that character set), and that's just the encodings I can think of off the top of my head.